# Return just the user specified columns based on user specified filters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am absolutely new with JavaScript and have been en-tasked with the following.

The environment is node.js, express, mongodb, mongoose.

Say, the DB/collection(s) contain 1000 rows and each row has 50 columns. A row may have null values for certain columns.

A user may enter certain filters - e.g., column 10, 20 - {'fruit': 'apple', 'price': '$20'}. Based on these filters, the rows are selected. But when the response reached the user, not all the columns (50 of them) are displayed. The user has the option to select columns and those selected are the only ones displayed. For example, the user sends the request with the filters above and column_selected as 5, 9, 21, 40. The maximum number of filters is 7 (the user may, for instance, select just 1 of the 7) and any number of columns (could be 1, could be all 50). The request has to be sent as a 'post' request. I was given the following code (for columns_selected) but it is not returning any data. I wrote the 'filters' part of the code and that isn't working either. I have included a sample request object as well. Any help will be appreciated. Having just been exposed to JS, I don't even have the right direction to solve this problem.

the request object:

request object :

```
{
               "filters": {
                               "a": "b",
                               "c": "d",
                               "3": "abc",
                               "d": "r"
               },
               "column_selected": ["a",
                               "ab",
                               "sw",
                               "ff",
                               "gg"
               ],
               "view_name": "my_view"
}
```

The response object:

Response_object :

```
{
               "user_views": [{
                                              "filters": {
                               "a": "b",
                               "c": "d",
                               "3": "abc",
                               "d": "r"
               },

                                               "column_selected": ["a",
                               "ab",
                               "sw",
                               "ff",
                               "gg"],
                                               "view_name": "my_view"
                               },
{
                                               "filters": {
                                   "a": "b",
                                   "c": "d",
                                   "3": "abc",
                                   "d": "r"
                   },
                                               "column_selected": ["a",
                                   "ab",
                                   "sw",
                                   "ff",
                                   "gg"],
                                               "view_name": "my_view2"
                               }]}
```

Code for column_selected

```
const express = require("express");
const url = require("url");
const router = express.Router();
const Data = require("../../models/Data");
const numberOfRecords = 1000;

router.post("", (req, res) => {
  columnsSelected = req.body.columnSelected;
  console.log(columnsSelected);

  var reqColumns = {};
  for (each of columnsSelected) reqColumns[each] = 1;
  reqColumns["_id"] = 0;

  // Data.find(req.body.filters, reqColumns)
  Data.find({}, reqColumns)
    .skip(req.body.noRows * req.body.pageNumber)
    .limit(req.body.noRows)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("in success");
      return res.json({ data: data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("in error");
      return res.send(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Code for filters:

```
const express = require("express");
//const url = require("url");
//const router = express.Router();
const router = require('express').Router();
const Data = require("../../models/Data");
//const numberOfRecords = 1000;

router.get("/getData", function(req, res) {
var filtersSelected = req.body.filters;

  Data.collection('getData').find({}, filtersSelected)
    .then(data => {
      console.log("in success");
      return res.json({ data: data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("in error");
      return res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: The projection part ("columns selected") seems alright at a first glance, the filtering bit would certainly need to be changed from `Data.collection('getData').find({}, filtersSelected)` into `Data.collection('getData').find(filtersSelected)` since the first argument to `find()` is the filter condition.

Comment: @dnickless - your answer worked. Additionally, I have to send the request as application/json . Thank you. (do you know how I can make your comment as the accepted answer? )

Comment: You can't. ;) I'm glad I could help. You could either simply delete your question because nobody else will ever have the same precise issue (or at least they won't find the answer to their potentially identical problem by searching because your question is super specific). Or you could answer yourself and accept it which is actually encouraged - you'll get a badge for that potentially (https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)!

Comment: @dnickless - thanks for the tip. Added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of @dnickless 's comment above. Two important things to keep in mind. The `find` function takes two arguments - `filters` and `projection columns`. The request sent must have the proper format - in my case, it was `application/json` .